# Remove specific element from the list

Tags: c#, list, linq

How can I remove each element(picture) from the list that has a `Tag` value smaller than a `Tag` value from some another picture, in my case `selectedPicture`. It doesn't allow me to use `<=` operator saying

---

Operator "<=" cannot be applied to operands of type "object" and "object".

---

Here is what I did:

```
pictureBoxList = pictureBoxList
  .Where(picture => picture.Tag <= selectedPicture.Tag)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: what type is `Tag` can you show the type / class definition?

Comment: what is the type of the value stored inside the `Tag` property?

Comment: I assume that this is type `Image` with `Tag` object attached to them set to an integer.

Comment: I know. `Convert.ToInt32` is solution. I totally forgot about converting it to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests you can't use `<=` to compare objects. You need to cast Tag property depending on what's the underlying type. For example if it's `int`:

```
.Where(picture => (int)picture.Tag <= (int)selectedPicture.Tag)
```

Comment: @fubo `Tag` is of type `object` and it's a member of class Control: [`Control.Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah.. My mistake. Forgot to convert it to int. Tnx